# General inheritance behavior / best practice wanted

Tags: inheritance, design-patterns

I have a general design pattern question converning inheritance of objects. No, I don't mean class inheritance like public class dog : animal, I need some "best practice" information on the following situation.

I have three classes of the same type with a name and different values. They have a hierachical order, so one is the parent, first and second child. Let's assume, every class should have a property called color.

I create an instance of a parent class and give it the color "BLUE". Now I create a child of the same type which should inherit all attributes by reference to the parent, as long as there is no special value set. It's not a clone, since I don't want to copy the values into the new class. So every change in the parent is automatically shown in the child.

So I create a new child under the first one - I don't have set any special color to the first one, so my second child is "BLUE", too. In short form it would look like this:

BLUE (Parent) --> BLUE (Child1) --> BLUE (Child2)

Now I change Child1 to "RED":

BLUE (Parent) --> RED (Child1) --> RED (Child2)

This would be a nice way to store only the differences to the base, so in case of large structures, I could simply save storage.

Any best practices for such a contruct / articles to read / links?

Thanks in advance

Roland

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this has been described before but I would design it like this:

First, give each of your classes a 'property set'.  In C++ this could be a map, mapping an identification (string, number, GUID, ...) to a value.

Then, give your classes a getColor method that works like this (this is incomplete code but should be enough to get you started):

```
PropertySet::const_iterator it = m_propertySet.find("Color");
// property found, return it
if (it!=m_propertySet.end()) return it->second;
// if property is not found, ask our parent
if (m_parent) m_parent->getColor();
// if no parent, return black
return BLACK;
```

Although this works, there are some pitfalls in this approach:

- looking up values in a property set is much slower than just returning a data member
- using a string as key in the property set is slow, but makes it easier to distinguish your properties
- using an integer as key in the property set is much faster, but can make it more difficult to distinguish your properties
- the property set will always take up more memory than just storing a data member, which probably only makes it feasible if you have a deep hierarchy, with many many properties of which there are only a few set

Comment: Was just about to post this same approach. You can get around the difficulties with using an integer as a key by just having an Enum specify all the valid properties. I think the pattern that most closely matches this is Chain of Responsibility.

Comment: Argh, enter is send ;)

Anyway, I could do this by a dictionary in C#. But as you said, I would always have to ask the parent "I have no color, tell me yours!" I hope that there is some kind ob reference to pass in such a way that could be extended somehow... But the dictionary is one way to achive this, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case of the [Delegation Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern).

Implementation of this kind of behavior depends on the language you are using. Prototype based languages, like Javascript or Self, use this mechanism natively. It means that you can establish a parent-child relation between two objects and immediately the child inherits all parent properties. When you change the value of a property in the parent object, you will see the new value in its children too. If you change a property in a child object, the new value is stored in the child and its parent is not affected.

If you use a language like Java or C++/C# you usually mimic this behavior holding in a member variable of an object (the child) a reference to another (its parent) and put in child's getters the necesary logic to look for a property value stored in the object itself (in a member variable or map), or delegate responsibility to its parent if child can't resolve the property by itself. Usually both child and parent implement a common interface, but I supose it's not always required.